# goto vs return for submenus and menus in C programming

Tags: c, goto

I I have a really quick question.
Which is more "standard" to use?
goto or returning a function?

goto example:

```
main(){
   start:
   //some code
   goto start;
}

main(){
   //some code
   return main();
}
```

Both will loop the script.
but I am wondering which one is more proper to use.

goto seems to be really good, but are there any disadvantages to using it? (I'm just wondering because an instructor failed a fellow student because of the goto function O.o and I'm wondering why, or what he did was reasonable.)

If you're asking why ask this, I am trying to create a menu with a submenu, where the submenu contains a "back" option (Where I would either use goto or return)

Comment: Both are different, 2nd will result in stack overflow while first one may not.

Comment: Well the second will cause a stack overflow since you're just recursively call yourself without any end conditions. Other than that it really depends on the situation, can you please elaborate on *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @Rohan that was helpful information.. thanks!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am trying to create a menu with a submenu, where the submenu contains a "back" option (Where I would either use goto or return)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here the reasonable thing to do is to use a loop. It has the same effect as a `goto` but is considered better practice as it follows the rules of [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) as opposed to the unmaintainable noodle soup programming that was common before.

```
int main(void) {
   while (1) {
      //some code
   }
}
```

Calling a function recursively could also be considered good style if the recursion had well-defined limits. Unlimited recursion in C usually leads to a stack overflow error, since few compilers implement tail-call optimization.

Comment: I will consider this Idea, but what I am actually trying to make is a back menu where the program has a main menu and a submenu.

the submenu will contain a "back" option that will return it to the main menu.

Comment: Make a function for menu and another for submenu, each with a loop. Make function for menu call the function for submenu to enter the submenu. Exit the loop when the user chooses the "exit" or "back" option.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that undefined behaviour?  I can find it documented that way for C++ only, but I've been pretty lazy.

Comment: You're right @sh1, the C standard seems to allow calling `main`, I can't find it forbidden anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`goto` should be avoided. using it is considered as a bad practice actually, since it make the code harder to read and understand.

I'm not sure that `return main();` is correct, in my opinion it's very ugly and not safe.

The better solution to do an infinite loop is to use `while(1)` or `for(;;)`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering what you need this for, loops and functions will do the trick:

```
void submenu(void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("a: Do something else\n");
        printf("b: Leave sub menu\n");

        char choice;
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        if (choice == 'a')
            do_something_else();
        else if (choice == 'b')
            break;  /* Break out of loop */
        else
            printf("Invalid choice.\n");
    }

    /* When this function returns, you get back to the main menu */
}

void mainmenu(void)
{
    int goon = 1;

    while (goon)
    {
        printf("1: Do something\n");
        printf("2: Enter sub-menu\n");
        printf("3: Exit\n");

        char choice;
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1':
            do_something();
            break;

        case '2':
            /* Enter the sub-menu */
            submenu();
            break;

        case '3':
            goon = 0;  /* This will cause the loop to end */
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    mainmenu();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `goto` when you have deep nestes loops where it is difficult to return from using `break`, for example.
When you use `return` in `main` you end the main-function and control is returned to the OS.

Your `goto`-implementation is causing an endless-loop and is far from accomplishing the same as return. Also, you should never call `main()` directly or indirectly.

Infinite loop will be realised using either

```
for(;;)
```

or

```
while(1)
```

these are more common, but your program will never end if you don't explicitly call `break` anywhere in the loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is one possibility. But consider for example driver-programming where you sometimes have deep-nested constructions and you have to make sure to clean up properly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just a bit more reasonable to make sense of your loops and end them properly (or using a break if you really have to) rather than throwing a goto in there? I mean, you have probably made those loops complex for a reason, goto will either make something explode or it'll make someone explode you when he's reading your code

Comment: This is just an example... Of course you should avoid `goto` and there is probabaly a different solution most of the time. But sometimes, especially in driver/kernel-programming it is an easy way to break out a nested construction.

Answer (score 0):

`return main()` is probably a bad idea because you can't guarantee that the compiler will optimise out the additional stack frames.  If the compiler failed to do that then your stack would continue to grow at every iteration of the loop.

It does re-initialise your local variables, but you can get the same effect by putting those variables inside a loop construct.

`goto` may have a place in some code, but this really isn't it.  If you want to loop then there are loop constructs for that.  Use `for (;;) { /* some code */ }` instead.